# How was the Golden Condor able to fly?

Tags: mysterious-cities-of-gold

In the 80's TV cartoon [The Mysterious Cities of Gold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysterious_Cities_of_Gold) there was a Golden Condor:

[image: The Golden Condor]

I remember it was somehow solar-powered, but I don't remember how
it flew. For instance, it did not flap its wings to take off.

By what principle was it able to fly?

Comment: +1 for adding a question about this cool series. (I thought about adding one myself but couldn't think of anything, so I'm very glad you did!)

Comment: I watched this as a kid, and it took me over 10 years to find another soul who had seen it. Everyone I asked had no idea what I was talking about. Neat question.

Comment: @zoe This series is well know in the French-speaking community. Everyone I know in my age group know the theme song.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this [Trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtFAT3tiCro) (sorry, in French only)  of the [upcoming second season of The Mysterious Cities of Gold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysterious_Cities_of_Gold#Sequel). This sequel is pretty official as one of the original writer, Jean Chalopin, is involved.

If you look at 3m30s you will see it taking off :

As you see, there is air coming from behind it, then the tail lights up as it move forward.

So, all we could conclude it the way the Golden Condor flew is intentionally kept mysterious, making it a even more incredible machine.

Answer (score 0):

It would have to be truly advanced/imaginary tech, like Niven's inertialess thrusters or gravity control.

The condor only glows occasionally when powering up or taking off. There is never any flapping, or any clear and consistent sign of thrust, nor any external structure that resembles any kind of engine. It can take off or land completely vertically and without any of the incredible winds kicked up by helicopters or VTOL/STOVL planes.

Source: I have been watching the DVDs and thinking a lot about this recently.